# Fetching meta tags from Angular 2 application for Open graph

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am trying to create a mechanism through which I can share some information in Facebook which consists of **Title, Description , Image**. On click of the link, it hits a REST endpoint in my application which will lead to a html page with meta tags (**Ex**.bots.html).
The problem is that, I couldn't get the correct images for my post in Facebook.

When I digged in deep with [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), I found out the following **warnings**

> Inferred Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided,
>   even if a value can be inferred from other tags. Inferred Property    The
>   'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can
>   be inferred from other tags. Inferred Property    The 'og:description'
>   property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be
>   inferred from other tags. Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property
>   should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from
>   other tags.

And when I click on "Scraped URL    See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL link", it takes me to the **index.html** contents where we dont have any meta tags.

How do I make sure that my **bots.html** contents are inferred rather than the **index.html** ?

***Architecture*** :

1.URL for Scraping contents

www.mysite/{dummy1}/{dummy2};

2.REST End-point in Angular application, which returns bots.html as view

/{dummy1}/{dummy2}

3.bots.html contents

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<!--Face book meta tags-->
<meta property="og:type" content="Site" />
<meta property="og:title" th:attr="content=${someValue.title}" />
<meta property="og:description" 
th:attr="content=${someValue.description}" />
<meta property="og:image" th:attr="content=${someValue.imageUrl}" />
<!--End-->
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var data = 0;
    var apiConfig = 0;
    data = /*[[${someValue}]]*/ +'';
    /*]]>*/
    window.location.href = window.location.origin;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The debug tool shows what path it followed in determining the final URL.

Comment: The path that is shown is correct but the 'See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL link' shows my index.html contents which is incorrect. And also when I hosted it with tomcat it was referring from bots.html

Comment: Impossible to tell what is going on with so little info. Example URL?

Comment: In simpler terms FB scraper is fetching index.html contents (which is my primary html) rather than the view (bots.html) returned by my REST end-point which is the final URL for shared link.

Comment: An actual URL that you are sharing would be a start, so that we can check what’s going on for ourselves.

Comment: According to my browser’s network panel, that returns only 906 bytes. Doesn’t even let me view “Preview” or “Response”, says “Failed to load response data” for both. Probably due to the automatic JS redirect, but no way for me to verify this actually returns what you say it does. And since the Facebook scraper seems to be of different opinion as well, this looks like you still messed something up somewhere. You say it “is fetching index.html contents”, but I would rather put that, it is _receiving_ the index.html contents from your system.

Comment: Yes there is a JS redirect to index.html on the bots.html which contains meta tags

Comment: _“on the bots.html which contains meta tags”_ - but apparently the Facebook scraper never gets to see those meta tags in the first place. The “See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL” link shows you what Facebook received from your system, and it has no reason to “lie” about that.